# Syntax/EOF error (easyphp)

Tags: php

my main page is a simple html webpage with a login button named "login". However whenever i press it nothing happens. The code below is named "validate.php" when i tried to open it i received a EOF/syntax error. Help is appreciated!

```
<?php

$myemail = "d";
$mypass = "d";

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass  = $_POST['password'];
    $rem   = $_POST['remember'];
    if($email == $myemail and $pass == $mypass){
    echo "logged in";       
    }
    else{
        echo "email or password is wrong";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Your curly brackets are unbalanced. Any editor with syntax highlighting would show you.

Comment: Also you want to replace the `and` in the condition with a `&&` ;-)